# I am a beginner in python.Need help in using collection

Tags: python

I want to create a function that create car object and adds to its collection of cars

```
cars={}
def add_car(model, price):
```

Comment: You have two steps, creating new `car` and adding an object to a dictionary. There are many tutorials and answers in SO on how to do each step.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?

**Option 1: If you meant object in the general sense.**

```
cars={}
def add_car(model, price):
    cars[model] = price
add_car("Subaru Forester",22000 )
print(cars)
```

Output: `{'Subaru Forester': 22000}`

This line `cars[model] = price` is how you add cars to the dict.

**Option 2: If by object you mean a Python object.**

```
class car:
  def __init__(self, model, price):
    self.model = model
    self.price = price

cars={}
def add_car(model, price):
    cars[model] = car(model, price)

add_car("Subaru Forester",22000 )
print(cars)
```

Output: `{'Subaru Forester': <__main__.car object at 0x00D1E9F0>}`

Comment: *I want to create a function that create car object* This doesn't create car object.

Comment: @Guy I admittedly assumed from the lack of code that they used object more generally. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @Matthew Its for the assignment but I can't seem to get my head around it. I have been asked to take user input for model and price of various cars and store it as collection of dictionary .

Comment: @SagarGiri both options do that. The question is whether you need an object/class.

Comment: I was told to use object to add in dictionary

Comment: Then you want option 2.

Comment: The weirdness is because class car is essentially a box full of stuff. The function doesn't know what is in the box, so it instead gives the location of the box. The weird numbers and letters are an address.

Answer (score -1):

```
cars = []

class car:
    def __init__(self, model, prize):
        self.model = model
        self.prize = prize


def add_car(model, price):
    c = car(model, price)
    cars.append(c)

add_car("Opel Astra", 22000 )
print(cars)
```

Comment: The OP asked about dictionary, not list. And your answer doesn't add anything to the existing answer.